# I can't install Steam

Tags: software-installation, steam

Although I installed steam millions of time in the past, I can't install steam on Kubuntu 20.10 today. It's a fresh install and everything works perfectly except Steam.

I tried to install it. I couldn't. I removed it, tried again, removed again, tried again..

Could you please guide me as step by step from this point?

Thank you very much.

Note: Current situation when I try to start steam from the terminal:

> bash: /usr/games/steam: No such file or directory

Comment: how did you install it

Comment: How are you installing steam?

Comment: At first, I tried discover software center, it didn't work. Then I removed it from the center and than I tried "sudo apt install steam". It installed; but after "checking for updates" little box, it just disappeared. Than I removed it again and tried to install via .deb package. This time package manager allowed me to install steam again; but it disappears again after the "checking for updates" little box. I mean I tried almost everyway; if I didn't do anything wrong.

Answer (score 3):

> sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386

> sudo apt install libnvidia-gl-450:i386

This solved my problem for those who has the same problem in the future.